# How can I link my AWS Managed AD to my FSx resources in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am quite new in cloudformation. Trying to create a template for AWS FSx with joining my AWS Managed AD. Here is what I did so far, when I execute in AWS CF console, it shows `Failed to retrieve external values` for AWS AD and seems like other options, I am able to select with dropdown; the AD one, I don't get a drop-down way to select my AWS managed Microsft AD.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
 MyAWSManagedADServiceID:
  Description: "AWS Managed Active Directoy Service ID, (e.g d-90670817d3)"
  Type: 'AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD'
  # Type: String
 StorageCapacity:
  Description: "Type the Storage Capacity value in TB, default '2TB' storage"
  Type: Number
  Default: 2000
 MyFSxVPC:
  Description: "VPC to operate FSx file FileSystem, (e.g vpc-05f3704057d6dce71)"
  Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
 MyPrivateSubnet01:
  Description: "The ID of Private Subnet 1 in Availability Zone 1 (e.g., subnet-a0246dcd)"
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
 MyPrivateSubnet02:
  Description: "The ID of the Private Subnet 2 in Availability Zone 2 (e.g., subnet-a0246dcd)"
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
 WindowsIngressSecurityGroupId:
  Description: "SecurityGroup ID for AWS FSx, (e.g sg-0fa88a05af8a49e03)"
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id

Resources:
  WindowsMadFileSystemWithAllConfigs:
    Type: 'AWS::FSx::FileSystem'
    Properties:
      FileSystemType: WINDOWS
      StorageCapacity: !Ref StorageCapacity
      StorageType: SSD
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet01
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet02
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WindowsIngressSecurityGroupId
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: my-fsx-multi-az
      WindowsConfiguration:
        ActiveDirectoryId: !Ref MyAWSManagedADServiceID
        ThroughputCapacity: 8
        WeeklyMaintenanceStartTime: '4:16:30'
        DailyAutomaticBackupStartTime: '01:00'
        AutomaticBackupRetentionDays: 2
        DeploymentType: MULTI_AZ_1
        PreferredSubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet01
        CopyTagsToBackups: false
Outputs:
  FileSystemId:
    Value: !Ref WindowsMadFileSystemWithAllConfigs
```

How can I get rid-off this error for AD and how can I select AWS Managed AD out of that drop-down menu?

[image: This is how it shows, not letting to select my AD]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured that "`Type: 'AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD`'" is not one of the parameters accepted by CF template. Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html 
Finally solved with using string type, however we can do `ssm` and use that.